# Concept for calculation with user given data and predefined data

Tags: php

I would appreciate some input regarding following computational concept.

I am new with `PHP/MYSQL` and therefore I am not sure about architecture of the following calculation problem:

Each user that comes to my webpage will have on option to enter 5 numbers which will be used for further calculations. Lets name them **$input1, $input2, $input3, $input4, $input5.**

Somewhere in the code in arrays or in the database ( this is yet to be determined - please suggest what you think it's best) will be a series of data.
For now lets say we have `30 arrays of data`.

Example of calculation:

Each of this numbers `$input(i)` will have an `IF statement` and depending on the `true/false` will be used with other numbers from `data(1)=array`.
Result of this computation will be stored in a newly created array => `Results(1)=array`.
Then different `$input(i)` is used for calculation with the same `data=array(1)` and result is saved in a newly created array=> `Results(2)=array`. etc... and so for calculation between all 5 `$inputs` with only 1 `data(1)=array`, result would be 5 different Results arrays.

Items inside this `results=arrays`  with the same index would be later summed up in a `final_result=array`. ( which will be displayed on the page) (summation of vectors basically)

And then this should loop for the other `29 arrays of data`.

My question is regarding concept.
Is it worthwhile to create a database of this data, because users will not input any data that will be saved to server.
Database, if used, will be only for reading data for calculation.
I (admin) will have to update this data 1-2 per month.
Any other comments, suggestions, which functions to use or how to simplify this problem are welcome.

thanks in advance, Jan

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming concepts, so http://programmers.stackexchange.com maybe a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the calculations take place within one page-session. Use arrays. If not use storage like database.

What i mean is, if the user posts something in x fields. These fields are processed then displayed on one page. This can and should be done in php. No need to save to db if you do not need to save preferences etc for user.

If there are several pages, one for each field-input for instance. The usage of databases and/or session-cookies might be a good idea.